# ARC - Instance message does not declare a method with selector

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, selector

i use this line of code :

`[self parseXMLFileAtURL:url];`

And i get this error :

> Automatic Refercence Counting Issue , Receiver type "xmlParser" for
>   instance message does not declare a method with selector
>   "parseXMLFileAtUrl

Any ideas what this is?

Comment: Does `self`actually has a method called `parseXMLFileAtUrl`?

Comment: by self u mean in the same controller? if thats right , yes the method is just below that!

Comment: Copy the method and paste it before your call. If this works, it means that you need to declare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something like this:

```
  -(void)myMethod{
     [self parseXMLFileAtURL:url];
   }

  -(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSURL*)myURL{
      // Some stuff
   }
```

Put like this:

```
 -(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSURL*)myURL{
      // Some stuff
   }

 -(void)myMethod{
     [self parseXMLFileAtURL:url];
  }
```

**If this works**, it means you need to go to your .h file and declare the method:

```
 -(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSURL*)myURL;
```

Or create a private interface in the .m file and declare it there.